# How to align columns in a table what have "w-full" class as like columns in table with the "w-auto" class?

Tags: html, css, class, tailwind-css

I have such a table:

```
<table class="w-full text-left">
      <thead>
        <tr class="border-b text-blue-900">
          <th class="p-3">Name</th>
          <th class="p-3">Email</th>
          <th class="p-3">Phone</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="border-b font-medium text-sm">
          <td class="p-3">Gustavo</td>
          <td class="p-3">gustavo.fring@gmail.com</td>
          <td class="p-3">+10000000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

With the `w-full` class, the columns in the table are spaced as far apart as possible, while I need to make them as close as possible, as is done with the `w-auto` class. But I can't change `w-full` to `w-auto`, because I use the `border-b` class for the `<tr>` tag and I need it to go the width of the page, as it happens with the `w-full` class in `<table>`.

I tried adding `flex justify-start` classes for `<tr>` but it makes the columns wavy because they no longer depend on the size of the text in the `<th>` and `<td>` tags like it does in a auto table.
It is necessary that the table works as a stack, when adding new columns, it does not change its width (as is done with w-auto ) and old columns do not move (as is done with w-full).

I found a table template for how I want to make mine, but the method doesn't work for me:[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZl4A.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to create another `<th>` element at the end of our `<tr>` element. We will then set the `<th>` element to be empty with a full width:

```html
<th class="w-full"></th>
```

This way:

```html
<table class="w-full text-left ">
  <thead>
    <tr class="border-b text-blue-900 ">
      <th class="p-3">Name</th>
      <th class="p-3">Email</th>
      <th class="p-3">Phone</th>
      <th class="w-full"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="border-b text-sm font-medium">
      <td class="p-3">Gustavo</td>
      <td class="p-3">gustavo.fring@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="p-3">+10000000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/gW5CjsWtLx)